# Send html "chunks" throught Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, cloudflare

I want to send a HTML in two parts:

First, I want to send a HTML in two parts. i.e: send the  element + a body with skeletons first,

Later, I want to send the final body and execute some javascript (removing the skeleton). This is a example but can be any other thing.

I can make this in the server (example in node-ish):

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
res.write('<html><head> things things things</head><body> skeleton skeleton')
await sleep(10_000)
res.write('body body body <script> removeSkeleton()</script></body></html>')
res.end()
```

This works great in my computer & in a remote server: I can see "skeleton skeleton skeleton" and ten seconds later I can see the "body body body". Good.

But when I upload this into our real servers this doesn't work well, we have Cloudflare in the middle. Yes, I can see "body body body" but no "skeleton skeleton" because I only receive the full response after 10 seconds, and not "by parts".

I'm not in the Devops team, and searching in internet only redirects me to Cloudflare workers.

There is any configuration inside Cloudflare, a HTTP header or something to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There was a NGINX in the middle, I added the header "X-Accel-Buffering: no" and works like a charm.